# HttpClient sending null values to api, not looking at json object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, umbraco

I am working with an ASP.NET website. I need to collect data from a form and send it to an api. PostAsync() requires two parameters, so I have to convert an object to JSON in order to send it. This is where my trouble lies as the api only receives null values. This is the relevant code I am looking at:

```
string apiurl = "http://localhost:5000/";

var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{apiurl}api/Contact/Create", content))
                    {
                        await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
```

Ultimatly, I need the api to recieve the values from the formData object. But the values it recieves are null.

I cannot tell if it is converting to JSON correctly. JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formData) is creating a string with my data accurately, and the formData object itself has my values. But when I inspect the content variable I cannot find that string anywhere.

This is the api header:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string listId, string email, string firstName, string lastName)
```

How do I:

1 - Verify that the json is correct?

2 - Send non-null values to the api?

EDIT:

As requested here is the class I made:

```
public class Report
    {
        public string listId { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set;  }
    }
```

And how I created the object:

```
Report formData = new Report {
                    listId = listId,
                    email = getFormValueFromKey(formModel.fieldNameValuePairs, "Email"),
                    firstName = "None",
                    lastName = "None"
                };
```

Comment: You have to show your Api header too, pls

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [Route("Create")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string listId, string email, string firstName, string lastName)

Answer (score 1):

since you are using a formdata, and your API parameters looks like key-value pair, I recommend you to try application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type

```
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
    var response = await PostAsync($"{apiurl}api/Contact/Create", content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(stringData);
    }
```

otherwise you will need to create a viewmodel and use frombody attribute.

UPDATE

Unfortunately I can't see your form data. But if it is not key value pair already, you can convert it to dictionary for example or better post it too , in order we could recomend how to use it better

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
             new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {

             {"listId", formData.listId},
             {"email", formData.email}
    }
    );
```

or if you want to use json then create viewmodel

```
public class Report
{
  public string listId {get; set;}
   public string email {get; set;}
   .....
}
```

and api

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Report model)
```

and code

```
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formdata);
    var content= new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: I tried to implement this but had to cast my formData object to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, the cast failed when it reached that point in my code.

Comment: You should show your form data. It is easier to cast to dictionary

Comment: I updated my question with the class I am using and the data I put into it

Comment: @Joe I update my answer too

Comment: So the api works, and it is best if I don't change it. I can if I have to, but is there a way to make it work with the api the way it is set up now?

Comment: @Joe If you  can't change an API use FormUrlEncodedContent and data as dictionary, the way  it  is shown in the first part of my answewr